# MultisubnetFailover as Connection string in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

How to utilize MultisubnetFailover=True/Yes - connection string in powerbuilder ini file?

SQLCA.dbParm = "DBTextLimit='32000',TrimSpaces=1,ProviderString='MARS Connection=False,MultiSubnetFailover=true',Database='"+SQLCA.Database+"',Initial Catalog='"+SQLCA.Database+"'"